# DJANGO gte, lte not showing any results

Tags: python, django

My Problem:

i wan't to check for upcoming events. I saw some posts about gte, lte etc. But if create a model query its not showing any results.

My code:

```
@login_required
def aufträge(request):
    aufträge = Aufträge.objects.filter(start_date__gt=datetime.now())


    context = {"aufträge":aufträge}
    return render(request, "aufträge/aufträge.html")
```

my model:

```
class Aufträge(models.Model):
    creator = models.IntegerField()
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Cars, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

any solutions?

Comment: As a German myself, I would strangle any dev in my team who used Umlauts (or any language other than English) in identifiers. You will avoid lots of trouble in general.

Comment: Yeah, youre right. Next time i will do it better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the *context* into the render() response, unless you have 0 records in your model, then I don't see any issues with your query except for the fact that no context is being passed.

```
@login_required
def aufträge(request):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    aufträge = Aufträge.objects.filter(start_date__gt=today)


    context = {"aufträge":aufträge}
    return render(request, "aufträge/aufträge.html", context)
```